# Scala Implicit Classtag without changing function contract

Tags: scala, reflection, implicit

I have a trait that is implementing a method defined in a supertrait with no arguments. My implementation of the method requires a type parameter that is defined on the trait, but I can't add an `(implicit ct:ClassTag[Foo])` because that would change the method's argument list and it no longer counts as implementing the method on the supertrait. Concretely:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait AbstractFoo
trait Performance
trait Performer {def perform:Performance}

class FooPerformer[Foo <: AbstractFoo](implicit ct:ClassTag[Foo]) extends Performance {
  // do things
}        

trait Fooer[Foo <: AbstractFoo] extends Performer {
  def perform = new FooPerformer[Foo]
}
```

I need the implicit `ClassTag` on `FooPerformer` to deal with an erasure in the implementation. As it stands, I get a compile error for a missing `ClassTag` on `perform` in `Fooer`, but if I change it to:

```
trait Fooer[Foo <: AbstractFoo] extends Performer {
  def perform(implicit ct:ClassTag[Foo]) = new FooPerformer[Foo]
}
```

It no longer implements `perform` on `Performer`.

Comment: I'm not getting a missing `ClassTag` error, so something is missing from your example. You could try making `Fooer` a class with the `ClassTag` as a constructor parameter, unless `Fooer` really has to be a trait.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner I just looked back at the original code that was causing this trouble and `FooPerformer` requires its own implicit `ClassTag` to deal with an erasure deeper down, I'd updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@wingedsubmariner meant:

```
scala> class Fooer[Foo <: AbstractFoo : ClassTag] extends Performer {
     |   def perform = new FooPerformer[Foo]
     | }
defined class Fooer
```

Also,

```
scala> trait Fooer[Foo <: AbstractFoo] extends Performer {
     |   implicit protected def tag: ClassTag[Foo]
     |   def perform = new FooPerformer[Foo]
     | }
defined trait Fooer

scala> class Foob extends Fooer[AbstractFoo] {
     | protected def tag = reflect.classTag[AbstractFoo]
     | }
defined class Foob
```

Comment: Delightful, thanks! I went with the second option because `Fooer` needs to remain a trait.